# How to bind a polyline in template?

Tags: wpf, templates, polyline

I am trying to bind the points of a polyline in control template. The points should bind to a point collection in the codebehind. My current xaml code is as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:LineDragThumb}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:LineDragThumb}">
                <Polyline Stroke="Transparent" Points="{Binding}"
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Should I need to make a dependency property to hold the point collection?

Please guide..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960101/1136211).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can have simple `Notifiable property of PointCollection` in your code-behind for binding but make sure you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to refresh the bindings on UI.

```
public PointCollection Points { get; set; }
```

And to bind on xaml you can do like this -

```
<Polyline Stroke="Transparent" Points="{Binding Points,
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```